# Python, subprocess in few threads are disappear

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I have a script that runs Threads which start `subprocess.Popen`. This script is monitoring all the output of subprocess and makes actions depends on sobprocess'es output. But sometimes the script close threads. Here is an example of my script:

```
import threading
import subprocess
import os

def doAction(): # Main actions which every thread do.
    command = "MyCommandForSubprocess"
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
                         shell=True, 
                         preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    command_output = iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

    while True: # Linstening of subprocess output.
        for line in command_output:
            if "(i)" in line:
                OutputMessages("Good News")
                parameter += 1
            if "(done)" in line:
                os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        break

    processesTested += 1
    OutputMessages("done")

def main()
    threadsLimited = raw_input("How many threads? ")
    threadsLimited = int(threadsLimited)

    actions = ["Thread(target=doAction, args=(parameter,))", "..."]

    for action in actions:
        # Limiter to chose how many threads to start simuntaneously.
        while True:
            if(int(activeCount()) <= threadsLimited):
                action.start()
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(.1)
                continue

    for thread in checkThreads:
        thread.join()
        activeCount()
```

When it start all the processes I can find all the `python` processes in system's monitor. But after few minutes the `python` processes went closed but `sh` processes are still active with `n/a` memory usage. Why do processes dissappear?